# Local WordPress & MAMP wp_remote_get(): cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, curl, mamp

I have a site running locally on MAMP Pro (macos) and keep getting cURL errors when I use `wp_remote_get()`

I've searched and tried multiple solutions, but nothing seems to work.

My code:

```
$url = site_url() . '/wp-json/wp/v2/my-cpt'; // This works just fine and shows up in the browser correctly
$response = wp_remote_get( $url ); // this outputs the cURL error: "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
```

I have:

1. Downloaded the latest CA file from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Replaced the cacert.pem file in my MAMP OpenSSL install: /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem
3. Opened the two relevant php.ini files. One is located at /Applications/MAMP/conf/php7.4.2/php.ini and the other at /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/conf/php.ini
4. Added the URL to the new cacert.pem curl.cainfo = "/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem" openssl.cafile = "/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem" openssl.capath = "/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs"
5. I also tried specifying curl.cainfo, openssl.cafile, openssl.capath
   via the MAMP GUI: File > Edit Template > PHP(php.ini) > 7.4.2

Comment: Ryan Dorn, did you find a solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a local work around.  You can disable SSL verification within your local site. This can be accomplished by adding this line into the file `wp-includes/functions.php` or
`/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/functions.php`

```
add_filter('https_ssl_verify', '__return_false');
```

Comment: That's all I needed, you saved my day